# druid and neutral alignment for planar wildshape

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, druid, alignment

One of my players is a druid and they recently took the feat [planar wild shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/planar-wild-shape). We ended up getting into an argument due to his neutral alignment.

> Good druids must use the celestial template
>
> evil druids must use the fiendish template.

At no point does it say anything about what happens with neutral. Which he read as whenever he uses the feat he gets to choose which template to add. But it could also be read as neutral druids gain no benefit from the feat. I view both as poor examples. I decided to use the [cleric rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric#TOC-Channel-Energy-Su-) since its the only example I know of which is similar.

> A good cleric (or a neutral cleric who worships a good deity) channels positive energy and can choose to deal damage to undead creatures or to heal living creatures. An evil cleric (or a neutral cleric who worships an evil deity) channels negative energy and can choose to deal damage to living creatures or to heal undead creatures. A neutral cleric of a neutral deity (or one who is not devoted to a particular deity) **must choose whether she channels positive or negative energy. Once this choice is made, it cannot be reversed.** This decision also determines whether the cleric can cast spontaneous cure or inflict spells (see spontaneous casting).

Have I misread or misunderstood the feat? Have I come up with a reasonable ruling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAW as a Neutral, Lawful or Chaotic Druid he can choose each time.

Your ruling isn't entirely unreasonable though - it is a powerful feat. However, if you stick to that ruling, I would give him the opportunity to pick a different feat if he wishes.

It's probably still worth him taking though.

Comment: I was afraid that they would be allowed to choose each time.

Comment: To be fair, the "standard" druid is neutral, not good nor evil. The good/evil restriction is an exception. If you are a good druid, you cant become a fiendish animal, if you are an evil druid, you cant become a celestial animal.